# Android app keeps crashing on emulator

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

my basic android app keeps crashing on my emulator.

This is my build.gradle.

```
buildscript {

// use the jcenter repository to download the dependencies
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.4.0-alpha6'
    }
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
}
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="fun.n.games"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.0" >


<application android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".HelloActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my HelloActivity

```
package fun.n.games;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hello_layout);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        textView.setText("Hello world!");
    }

}
```

I am trying to get this thing together without using AndroidStudio. I am stitching them together on Sublime and then using command line tools to get them to show up in emulator.

I run my emulator from command line, like so.

```
emulator -avd Default
```

I build and deploy my code onto the AVD using gradle like so.

```
$ gradle installDebug
```

My app shows up in the emulator but whenever I click on it, it crashes. It does not find the HelloActivity.

This is what the logs have to say.

```
AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{fun.n.games/fun.n.games.HelloActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "fun.n.games.HelloActivity"
```

This is the AVD that I am running this on.

```
$ android list avd
Available Android Virtual Devices:
    Name: Default
    Path: /Users/me/.android/avd/Default.avd
  Target: Android 7.0 (API level 24)
 Tag/ABI: default/x86_64
    Skin: WVGA800
```

Any help?

Comment: if you run `adb logcat` is there a stack trace of the crash?

Comment: We need to see some sort of error logs to be of any help - "it crashes" is essentially a useless statement without them.

Comment: try using the full name in your manifest: `android:name="fun.n.games.HelloActivity"`

Comment: Tried using full name. No. Still the same problem. Where are the .class files supposed to be?

Comment: Paste your layout and emulator specs. What is the version of emulator?

Comment: Just added my **AVD** details.

Comment: Try going to project root and run **./gradlew installDebug** instead of gradle...

Comment: The same as the solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43423655/apk-file-does-not-contain-the-java-file