# apk file does not contain the java file

Tags: android, gradle

Am getting the following error

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 3069): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{fun.n.games/fun.n.games.HelloActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "fun.n.games.HelloActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/fun.n.games-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
```

This error shows up when I try to execute my android app that I have installed on my AVD.

My AVD is running as follows

```
$ emulator -avd Nexus_S_API_22
```

The code for the HelloActivity is present.

```
package fun.n.games;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hello_layout);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        textView.setText("Hello world!");
    }

}
```

It is being pulled together by the following manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="fun.n.games"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.0" >


<application android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="fun.n.games.HelloActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is being built by a single build.gradle

```
buildscript {

// use the jcenter repository to download the dependencies
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
}
```

And I am using gradle from command prompt to build and install

```
$ gradle installDebug
```

Apart from the error at the beginning of the post, when I search through the build folder, I don't see the HelloActivity.class that I was expecting there.

How do I get the java class to get added to the apk file?

Comment: try disabling instant run

Comment: I am not using AndroidStudio. How do I disable instant run from command prompt?

Answer (score 1):

Replace  `android:name="fun.n.games.HelloActivity"` with  `android:name=".HelloActivity"`

Answer (score 0):

Gradle was indeed not finding the java files to compile. Reason being my java file was in the wrong location.

**Incorrect location**

/src/main/fun/n/games/HelloActivity.java

**Correct location**

/src/main/**java**/fun/n/games/HelloActivity.java

The **java** folder was missing and hence gradle was not finding the class to compile.